# How to read file that belongs to other app from external storage?

Tags: android, file

I want to read text file, that was written by other my app. It's saved ad "Android/data/MyPackageName/files/"

I use this code:

```
 File file = new File("//Android//data//MyPackageName//files//", "filename.txt");
 FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
```

but i get exception "no such file or directory"

I am sure that solution is pretty simple, but i can't find it yet.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it in the sd card or internal storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is right to use the double backslash "//", one is enough. Also, the path should be "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data....". I am not sure the "/mnt/sdcard" is applicable on every device, so my suggestion is to use [Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).getExternalStorageDirectory to get the root dir on sd card.